# Azure DevOps - Trigger another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I got two pipelines in my project, one for test and one for build. The reason for this is that the tests need to be run on an self hosted agent to be able to run integration tests.

I don't want to run the build pipeline if the tests are failing. This is my configuration:

Test (Pipeline name)

```
name: Test

trigger:
  - azure-pipelines

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

steps:
  - script: echo Test pipeline
```

Build (Pipeline name)

```
name: Build

trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: test
      source: Test
      trigger: true

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

steps:
  - script: echo Build pipeline
```

The Test pipeline is running as expected but the Build pipeline never gets triggered even if I run it in the cloud as in the example above. Anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Why don't you consider multiple stages pipeline, where you could use dependsOn previous stage success or fail

Comment: What I know, it's not possible to have different VM/Agents for different stages

Comment: I have provided you an example, it is possible to run different vm/agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to call another pipeline as shown in the other answer but to start a different agent OS, I would suggest using a Multistage pipeline or Strategy Matrix.

Each stage can run with its own VM or Agent pool.

Here is an example:

```
trigger:
- main

stages:  
- stage: Build  
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  jobs:  
  - job: BuildJob  
    steps:  
    - script: echo Building
- stage: TestWithLinux
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  jobs:  
  - job: Testing
    steps:
    - script: echo Test with Linux OS
- stage: TestWithWindows
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:  
  - job: Testing
    steps:
    - script: echo Test with Windows OS
- stage: Final
  dependsOn: [TestWithLinux,TestWithWindows]
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  jobs:  
  - job: FinalJob
    steps:
    - script: echo Final Job
```

You can replace vmImage: xxx with your own hosted Agent like:

```
pool: AgentNameX
```

And the final result would look like this:

[image]

Or It is possible to use a strategy with the matrix. Let's say we have a code that should be run on 3 different agents, we can do the following:

```
jobs:  
- job:
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Linux:
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      Mac:
        imageName: 'macOS-latest'
      Windows:
        imageName: 'windows-latest'
  pool:
    vmImage: $(imageName)
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      "OS = $($env:AGENT_OS)" | Out-Host
    displayName: 'Test with Agent'
```

It can work as a stand-alone or in multi-stages as well as shown in the  image:

[image]

Here is a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) of supported hosted agents.

> Disclaimer: I wrote 2 [articles](https://itbackyard.com/?p=1961) about this in my personal blog.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the correct pipeline name. I would also suggest adding `project` inside resources pipeline.

For example I have a pipeline named first.

*first.yml*

```
 trigger:
 - none
 pr: none
 pool:
   vmImage: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
 - script: echo Running the first pipeline, should trigger the second.
   displayName: 'First pipeline'
```

*second.yml*

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: first
    source: first
    project: test-project
    trigger: true # Run second pipeline when the run of the first pipeline ends

steps:
- script: echo this pipeline was triggered from the first pipeline
  displayName: 'Second pipeline'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two pipeline definitions seem to be correct. You may try checking the following configurations from the Azure DevOps portal.
(I guess you are using GitHub)

1. Make sure the Build pipeline definition is in the default branch. Or else, you can configure its branch as the default branch for the Build pipeline from the Azure DevOps portal.

Go to pipeline -> Edit -> More options -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get Sources ->
Then change the value in `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` to the branch which holds pipeline yaml.

2. Configure the **Build Completion** trigger under triggers.

Go to pipeline -> Edit -> More options -> Triggers -> Build completion -> Add -> then select the **Test pipeline** as the `Triggering build` from the drop down. Also, add the listed branch filer too (if needed).

This will make sure that the pipeline completion trigger is completed correctly since portal configuration hold the highest priority.

P.S. Better to disable the PR trigger as well with `pr: none` config in the yaml if it is not required as default.